# How to pass arguments to Python script or read config files in Python scripts when using Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

For example, I'm submitting a python script `my_driver.py` to Flink by running `bin/flink run --python my_driver.py`. Can I pass any user-defined arguments to `my_driver.py`? Or can I open and read a config file in `my_driver.py`